# AES-CBC (256bit) Different outputs between C++ and PHP

Tags: c++, aes, encryption-symmetric

I am currently attempting to implement the AES-CBC encryption algorithm into my C++ Code. I am sourcing the code from this github https://github.com/WaterJuice/WjCryptLib and the only issue I have had with it, is that the output coming from the C++ code is completely different from the PHP implementation. I was previously using the CryptoPP library and the outputs did line up sufficiently when using the exact same algorithm. I assume it could be to-do with the padding but this honestly all goes way over my head and I am having a very hard time understanding the actual issue with this code as it does Encrypt and Decrypt properly, just only within its own set of functions.

**PHP:**

```
function NEncrypt($String, $EncKey, $IV)
{
    return openssl_encrypt($String, 'aes-256-cbc', $EncKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IV);
    return NULL;
}

$EncryptedString = NEncrypt("SecreteKey", "12345678901234567890123456789012", "1234567890123456");
die($EncryptedString);
```

**CPP:**

```
uint8_t CypherText[32] = { 0 };

std::string InputText = "SecreteKey";
std::string IV = "1234567890123456";
std::string Key = "12345678901234567890123456789012";

AesCbcEncryptWithKey((uint8_t*)Key.data(), Key.size(), (uint8_t*)IV.data(), InputText.data(), CypherText, 32);

std::cout << "Encrypted Text > " << CypherText << "\n";

AesCbcDecryptWithKey((uint8_t*)Key.data(), Key.size(), (uint8_t*)IV.data(), CypherText, CypherText, 32);

std::cout << "Decrypted Text > " << CypherText << "\n";
```

**PHP Output:** ��� |�{aw�q"

**CPP Output:** Encrypted Text >        ╝Ω√|rBs8Σ5SÜû£‼┌]NV¿O ↓╛û☼OÅ"Qπiú§╒a♥ Decrypted Text > SecreteKey

I completely understand if me using WjCryptLib makes it difficult to help me, I should mention that I am no opposed to using a different code base, it just cannot be a packaged library as I need to make all of the functions in-lined. Thanks in advance for any possible help.

Comment: The plaintext has a length of 10 bytes. CBC is a block cipher mode, PHP/OpenSSL uses PKCS#7 padding by default, so the ciphertext has a length of 16 bytes. Note that a ciphertext should not be decoded with a charset encoding like UTF-8 (especially with regard to a comparison), but should be encoded with a binary-to-text encoding like Base64 (`base64_encode()`) or hex (`bin2hex()`).

Comment: @Topaco I do agree that this is not the best for comparison, however I did not include the code that I was using to convert "bin2hex". Even after doing so on both ends the output was still wildly wrong. The length is especially as of note, I only did that to make things simple with this post.

Comment: @273K I just pasted Decrypted Text from the Console, it was on a new line when It was initially displayed sorry about that confusion

Comment: A charset encoding usually corrupts the ciphertext, i.e. you compare corrupted data! At least a hex encoding is not difficult even in C/C++.